# Comparison of a Char Pointer to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, null, comparison

I am running my code on SUSE Linux. I have a pointer which I make = NULL in a function. But the problem arises when I try to compare the same pointer with NULL in a while loop. This is leading to the program crashing. I have reproduced my problem in the sample code below. Can someone please tell me what is happening here?

My code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(char *,int);

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    int i =20;

    int temp = func(buffer,i);

    if ( (temp == 0) && (buffer != NULL) )
    {
        printf("inside loop \n");
    }
}

int func(char *ad,int a)
{
    ad = NULL;
    printf("Integer is %d \n", a);
    return(0);
}
```

The problem is that the comparison, `buffer != NULL` is failing and the control goes inside the loop, which should not be happening ideally. I have resolved this, by doing this:

`ad[0] = NULL` and the comparison changed to `buffer[0] != NULL`.

Since NULL is used only in a pointer context, this is bad code. I could use '\0's instead of the NULL in my workaround and get away with not writing 'bad code', but I really want to know what is happening here. Can someone please clarify?

Thanks a ton, 
Aditya

Comment: There is no loop here. What loop are you talking about?

Comment: `NULL` is used to compare with pointers. Its macro expands to a null pointer constant. So `buffer[0] != NULL` isn't correct, because `buffer[0]` is of `char` data type.

Answer (score 6):

buffer isn't a pointer, it cannot be NULL.

Your `func` sets the *copied address of buffer* to NULL. That does not affect buffer at all.

EDIT: Extended explanation

```
char buffer[20];
```

This reserves 20 bytes somewhere on stack. They're not initialized in any way. As you have 20 bytes of memory, obviously these bytes must reside at some address.

```
int temp = func(buffer,i);
```

This takes the *address of* your 20 bytes in buffer, and passes it to func.

```
int func( char *ad,int a)
{

ad = NULL;
```

Here you have, at a new position on stack, a new pointer variable which will exist only while `func` is executing. This pointer variable *is at* an address, and *points to* an address. You change this pointer, which affects where it points. But it will not change your original buffer in any way, since `ad` is only a temporary variable on stack that contained the address of the bytes in your `buffer` variable (until you set this temporary variable to NULL).

Comment: Thanks! I got it now, great explanation. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

1. In `func`, you're attempting to modify the value of `ad`, *not* what `ad` points to.  This won't work, as changes to the parameter value are not reflected in the caller.  You would need to change that code to

   ```
   int func(char **ad, int a)
   {
     *ad = NULL;
     printf("Integer is %d\n", a);
     return 0;
   }
   ```

   Unfortunately, this won't work with the rest of the code, since...
2. `buffer` is declared as an array object, not a pointer, and you cannot modify an array object; IOW, `buffer` cannot be assigned to.  Not to mention that the type of `&buffer` is `char (*)[20]`, not `char **`.

Here's a modified version of your source that will "work", although I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20

int func(char **ad, int a)
{
  *ad = NULL;                   // WOOPA! WOOPA! MEMORY LEAK!!! MEMORY LEAK!!!
  printf("Integer is %d\n", a);
  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * SIZE);
  int i = 20;
  int temp = func(&buffer, i);
  if (temp == 0 && buffer != NULL)
    printf("Inside loop\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I was trying to do was to read a file record by record using fgets. After the last record, I wanted to make the "buffer" NULL and compare it in the caller. This was not happening and hence a crash.